# jackson serialize map to a list of customized output

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

I have a `Map<EquipmentType, Integer> equipment` to store equipment quantity.
I'd like to serialize this map as

```
{"equipment":
  [
    {"equipmentType":{},"quantity": 0},
     ...
  ]
}
```

I have a customized serializer

```
public void serialize(Map<EquipmentType, Integer> value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
    gen.writeStartObject();
    value.entrySet().forEach(entry -> {
        try {
            gen.writeObjectField("equipmentType", entry.getKey());
            gen.writeNumberField("quantity", entry.getValue());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    gen.writeEndObject();
}
```

But it only write one entryset.

```
"equipment" : 
  {
    "equipmentType" : {},
    "quantity" : 1
  }
```

what should I do to concatenate entrysets to a list?

Comment: does it executes your lambda more than once?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You're currently writing a single object for the entire `Map<EquipmentType, Integer>`. Jackson's behavior for duplicate JSON object fields is to overwrite, so only the last entry in your `Map` will be written as the single JSON object you're writing.

You'll want to start a JSON array, write each entry as an object, then close the array.

For example,

```
public void serialize(Map<EquipmentType, Integer> value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider)
        throws IOException {
    gen.writeStartArray();
    value.entrySet().forEach(entry -> {
        try {
            gen.writeStartObject();
            gen.writeObjectField("equipmentType", entry.getKey());
            gen.writeNumberField("quantity", entry.getValue());
            gen.writeEndObject();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    gen.writeEndArray();
}
```

<sub>But also, you should get rid of the `forEach`. Use a normal `for` statement.</sub>